# Singleton Module & importing global jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, singleton

In an attempt to improve the way I code I have been reading about the Singleton Module. Which I think I have fully grasped however I have seen an example that imports jquery as a global, however I was unable to reference a DOM element like below:

```
var bnTalent = (function ($) {
    var bnt = {},
        privateVariable = 1;
    domRef = $("#pie").val();

    function privateMethod() {
        // ...
    }

    bnt.moduleProperty = 1;
    bnt.init = function () {
        alert("bingo" + domRef);
        //domRef.hide();
    };

    return bnt;
}(jQuery));
```

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>bnTalent</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bnTalent.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>

<input type="text" id="pie" value="mypies" />
</body>

</html>
```

Please remember this code is just me playing around to gain an understanding, but wondering why I can not retrieve the value of a DOM element from within the closure. Have I missed the point or have I made some school point error? Please note the element exists in the DOM and jQuery is loaded before this module. Also this is not an attempt at creating a jQuery plugin.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Please note I am just using firebug to execuete the init method after the dom has loaded.

****GOT IT WORKING - Hi I added var in front of the global var domRef and this seemed to fix the problem - could anyone explain why ? 
Also it seemed I can use domRef with out declaring var however the variable above needed to be "1" we live and learn lol

---

Comment: Are you running that code inside a `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: Seems like I can retrieve it: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/8ERqF/ -- are you using `val()` on a form input? Or should you be using `text()` or `html()` instead?

Comment: no i was'nt i was just loading the module then calling the function from within firebug after the dom had loaded.

Comment: I think there must be something wrong with the way I am defining the private var (domRef), as I can output alert($("#pie").val()); and referencing it direct.

Comment: Hi I added var in front of the global var domRef and this seemed to fix the problem - could anyone explain why ?

Answer (score 1):

This works: http://jsfiddle.net/J9PKB/ what exactly are you not able to do?

**Edit**

You're not using the `init` method anywhere..., are you hoping it'll get call automatically? Because it won't. You have to call it yourself.

Add this on your head tag, after including your JS files:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {  bnTalent.init(); } );
</script>
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: ha ha exactly what you have just done. Was trying to see if I could access the doms value - not sure why it won't run on my side, must be a school boy error somewhere.

Comment: I copy&pasted your code, are you calling the "init" method on the document.ready? Are you sure the id is correct? Maybe posting the whole thing will help us spot the error.

Comment: Hi no I was'nt call it, I was calling it using firebug after the dom had loaded - it still returns undefined however if I take val() off it return me object object so it seems to be able to find the dom reference ?

Answer (score 1):

```
function bnTalentFactory($){
    if(bnTalentFactory.bnt)
        return bnTalentFactory.bnt;
    if(arguments.length == 0 || arguments[0] != jQuery)
        var $ = jQuery;
    var bnt = {},
        privateVariable = 1,
        domRef;

    function privateMethod() {
        // ...
    }

    bnt.jqueryIsDefined = function(){
        return $ === jQuery;
    }
    bnt.moduleProperty = 1;
    bnt.init = function () {
        domRef = $("#pie").val();
        alert("bingo" + domRef);
        //domRef.hide();
    };
    bnTalentFactory.bnt = bnt;
    return bnt;
}

var bnTalent = bnTalentFactory();
var anotherBnTalent = bnTalentFactory();
alert(bnTalent === anotherBnTalent);// true => the same instance
alert(bnTalent.jqueryIsDefined());// true => jquery is defined inside this object, withouth even passing it to the factory
```

Note that in order to have a valid "domRef", you need to execute this code after the dom is loaded, so that `$("#pie")` exists at execution time.

Comment: thanks for your answer and presenting me with another pattern, I managed to find my problem in the end. Thanks for your time